# Python env - ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python

I use a third-party source checked out from svn.

It was building and running fine. But while creating a deploy script, I may have executed some cmd after which I keep getting error

```
ImportError: cannot import name XXX
```

where XXX changes randomly.

I think my environment on Mac may be corrupted.

How can I find and resolve the issue?

Comment: are you sure you didn't name your script after a built-in module?

Comment: yes...I am sure its not named after a built-in script. I just tried bulidng/running on EC2 instance, it works as expected. Python virtualEnv did not help (same issue). Not sure whats wrong

Comment: Ok..it was my config issue. I removed all the dirs that were ever created as part of this process and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a virtual environment. For example, virtualenv. Once you create a virtual environment, activate it via `source env/bin/activate` and install all of the dependencies via `pip install`. You can start to narrow it down from there.